# Add dropdown to side navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to add an onClick to my nav bar dropdown icon (the arrow) and the "Drop" title that will show and un-show the social networks, with a sliding animation.

So imagine at first imagine there is only the phone, arrow, and user icons /w titles, and when you click on the arrow the social networks icons and text appears sliding down.

Here's what I've achieved so far:

http://codepen.io/apswak/full/jVJmxV/

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible the way I've written it, if so how I can achieve this?

Thanks

PS: I'm writing it in react, here's the code:

`LeftNav.js:`

```
import NavIcons from './NavIcons'
import NavText from './NavText'
import NavInfo from './NavInfo'

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="nav" className="nav">
            <NavIcons/>
            <NavText/>
            <NavInfo/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`NavIcons.js:`

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class NavIcons extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon">
        <ul>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><Link to="/"><i className="fa fa-table"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><Link to="/"><i className="fa fa-line-chart"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><Link to="/#/fb"><i className="fa fa-facebook fb-col"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><Link to="/#/twit"><i className="fa fa-twitter twit-col"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><Link to="/#/ig"><i className="fa fa-instagram ig-col"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><Link to="/#/ga"><i className="fa fa-google ga-col"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><Link to="/#"><i className="fa fa-object-group"></i></Link></li>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><Link to="/#"><i className="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`NavInfo.js:`

```
export default class NavInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="info">
        <img width="50px"
          alt="Logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Cool_TV_logo_2004.svg/2000px-Cool_TV_logo_2004.svg.png"
          class="navbar-logo"/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="social">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook tang-nav-social"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram tang-nav-social"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`NavText.js:`

```
export default class NavText extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li class="main-nav-btn"><a href="#">Call</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav-btn"><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav-btn fb-col"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav-btn"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="sub-nav-btn ig-col"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav-btn"><a href="#">Title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set this up using your base code on codepen. It should run fine below if you run the snippet. I added two CSS classes for you and send an event handler prop to both of your components that need elements hidden. I changed the top level element to be stateful so it can manage the change in CSS classes of the various components. Some minor stuff was changed to get it working in SO snippet environment so take a look at the specific changes I made to your components and some of the JSX and you should be able to adapt it to your code pretty easily.

I didn't have time to setup the animation for you, but the easiest way would probably be the jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` functions even though using it with react is less than ideal. Using pure react (the ideal way) you would setup a `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup />`

[More info on that here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

Its kind of challenging, but you should be able to get it working properly with your current code base and with some slight modifications to what I did for you.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar />
    );
  }
}

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      swtichClass: 'drop-menu drop-hide',
    };
    this.changeClass = this.changeClass.bind(this);
  }
  changeClass() {
    if(this.state.swtichClass === 'drop-menu drop-hide') {
      this.setState({swtichClass: 'drop-menu'});
    } else {
      this.setState({swtichClass: 'drop-menu drop-hide'});
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="nav" className="nav">
            <NavIcons classState={this.state.swtichClass} changeClass={this.changeClass} />
            <NavText classState={this.state.swtichClass} changeClass={this.changeClass} />
            <NavInfo/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
class NavIcons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.chevSwitch = this.chevSwitch.bind(this);
  }
  chevSwitch() {
    if(this.props.classState === 'drop-menu drop-hide'){
      return 'fa fa-chevron-circle-right';
    } else {
      return 'fa fa-chevron-circle-down';
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon">
        <ul>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
          <li className="main-nav-btn" onClick={this.props.changeClass}><a href="#"><i className={this.chevSwitch()}></i></a></li>
          <div className={this.props.classState}>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-facebook fb-col"></i></a></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-twitter twit-col"></i></a></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-instagram ig-col"></i></a></li>
          </div>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-user-circle"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class NavInfo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="info">
        <img width="50px"
          alt="Logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Cool_TV_logo_2004.svg/2000px-Cool_TV_logo_2004.svg.png"
          className="navbar-logo"/>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="social">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i className="fa fa-facebook tang-nav-social"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com"><i className="fa fa-instagram tang-nav-social"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class NavText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="text">
        <ul>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><a href="#">Call</a></li>
          <li className="main-nav-btn" onClick={this.props.changeClass}><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
          <div className={this.props.classState}>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn fb-col"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li className="sub-nav-btn ig-col"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
          </div>
          <li className="main-nav-btn"><a href="#">Title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.drop-hide {
  display:none !important;
}
.drop-menu {
  display: block;

}
.nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: -2em;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 150px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
}
.navbar-logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  /*right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;*/
}
.fb-col {
  color: #3B5998 !important;
}
.twit-col {
  color: #1DA1F2 !important;
}
.ig-col {
  color: #635AC8 !important;
}
.nav .icon .circle {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px #222;
  margin-top: -18px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav .icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 990;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%, #000000 0%, #000000 10%, #1c1c1c 91%, #2c2c2c 100%, #111111 100%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 10%,#1c1c1c 91%,#2c2c2c 100%,#111111 100%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 10%,#1c1c1c 91%,#2c2c2c 100%,#111111 100%,#131313 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
.nav .icon li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav .icon a {
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.main-nav-btn {
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.sub-nav-btn {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.nav .icon a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.nav:hover .text {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.nav .text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 63px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 980;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%, #000000 0%, #000000 10%, #1c1c1c 91%, #2c2c2c 100%, #111111 100%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 10%,#1c1c1c 91%,#2c2c2c 100%,#111111 100%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 10%,#1c1c1c 91%,#2c2c2c 100%,#111111 100%,#131313 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .24s linear;
  transition: -webkit-transform .24s linear;
  transition: transform .24s linear;
  transition: transform .24s linear, -webkit-transform .24s linear;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) translateX(-200px);
          transform: perspective(1000px) translateX(-200px);
}
.nav .text li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.nav .text a {
  display: block;
  text-indent: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.nav .text .main-nav-btn {
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav .text .sub-nav-btn {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.nav .text a:hover {
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-8px);
          transform: translateX(-8px);
}
.nav:hover .info {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in 0.1s;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.nav .info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 165px;
  z-index: 998;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6;
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav .info .logo p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%, #000000 0%, #000000 10%, #1c1c1c 91%, #2c2c2c 100%, #111111 100%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 10%,#1c1c1c 91%,#2c2c2c 100%,#111111 100%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 10%,#1c1c1c 91%,#2c2c2c 100%,#111111 100%,#131313 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

  color: #424242;
  opacity: .6;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px #4f4f4f, 1px 1px #121212;
}
.nav .info .logo p:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px #575757, 1px 1px #121212;
}
.nav .info .name {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #E98300;
}
.nav .info .kicker {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.nav .info .quote {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #121212;
}
.social {
  display: inline-block;
}
.social a {
  color: red;
}
.nav .info .social a {
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.nav .info .social a:hover {
  color: whitesmoke !important;
  /*text-shadow: -1px -1px #222, 1px 1px #333;*/
}
.tang-nav-social {
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tang-nav-social: hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 550px) {
  .nav .info {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .nav h1 {
    font-size: 7.5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for this question is to read through the example given on fb react website: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

And then inside the LeftNav.js:

Add onClick functions and handleClick functions for the UI component you want to modify.